# How can I set my own order for an Enumeration in Latex?

Tags: enums, latex, customization, enumeration, items

I want the items in my enumerations of the second level to look like this everytime in this order:

```
Binary:                                                  i)
Decimal:                                                ii)
Hex:                                instead of:        iii)
Subtraction:                                            iv)
Addition:                                                v)
```

(I don't care how they continue after the 5th `\item` because I won't use more than 5 anyway.)

I'm not sure if it's possible I  just googled around and it seems one can only use this to change the item names: `\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\roman{enumii}: }` but this only works with standard orders...well I'm not gonna talk too much about it because I'm very new to Latex so here's my code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Question 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \item
        \item 
        \item 
        \item 
    \end{enumerate}
\item Question 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \item
        \item 
        \item 
        \item 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `description` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question 1
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
    \item fifth
  \end{enumerate}

  \item Question 2
  \begin{description}
    \item[Binary:] first
    \item[Decimal:] second
    \item[Hex:] third
    \item[Subtraction:] fourth
    \item[Addition:] fifth
  \end{description}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

An automated way using an new environment called `qlist`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{qlist}
\newenvironment{qlist}
  {\setcounter{qlist}{0}% Restart qlist counter
   \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{% Update \descriptionlabel
     \hspace{\labelsep}\normalfont% Taken from article.cls
     \stepcounter{qlist}% Increment counter
     \ifcase\value{qlist}\relax\or% 0
       \textbf{Binary:}\or% 1
       \textbf{Decimal:}\or% 2
       \textbf{Hex:}\or% 3
       \textbf{Subtraction:}\or% 4
       \textbf{Addition:}\else% 5
       Unknown% Unknown entry
    \fi}%
   \begin{description}}% begin normal description environment
  {\end{description}}% end normal description environment

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question 1
  \begin{qlist}
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
    \item fifth
  \end{qlist}

  \item Question 2
  \begin{qlist}
    \item first
    \item second
  \end{qlist}

  \item Question 3
  \begin{qlist}
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
    \item fourth
    \item fifth
  \end{qlist}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, maybe I didn't ask precisely enough -
I'm looking for something that automates this, because I don't want to have to write `\item[Binary:]` every time ;(
I just want to write \item and the program should know which one it is and put in the right value.

Comment: @Cold_Class: I've updated the answer to include an automated itemized approach.

Comment: Wow, this looks complicated O.o but I will go through it step by step until I understand it! 
thank you so much!!! :) :)

Comment: @Cold_Class: I guess, like a car, if it runs with an automatic transmission, it's easy to use, but requires some extra work which should be hidden from the driver. In this case, the content in the preamble (between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`) is the stuff that should be hidden from the driver. So, just use it and don't look at it.

Comment: Nah, I'm an IT Student so I am interested in the way those things work on the inside :D just very new to LaTeX so it will need a bit of time until I get it.